# Why does Disabled android app has an option "Force Stop"?

Tags: android

I see the description of "Disable" and "Force Stop" operations on Android devices for apps as:

> Force stop will temporarily stop the app from running in the background. The app will start running again as soon as you open it next time whereas Disable will close the application from the phone and you will not be able to use the application again unless you enable it again from settings

But why do disabled apps have an option "Force Stop"? They should not be running as per above definition and there should be nothing to stop.

[image: Disabled app has option to "Force Stop"]

That behaviour is even observed after a phone restart.

Moreover, "Force Stop" is not available for all disabled apps.

[image: Some disabled apps do not have "Force Stop" action]

Comment: Disable just prevents the app from being started. Force stop is useless if the app is disabled, but it works as intented: After you press it, the app is not running. In a similar way, the Force stop is also present for apps that are not running at all whle being enabled. Force stop just kills all processes related to that application, whether there are any or not.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl If "Force stop" exists independently if process is running or not, and does nothing if process is not running, why isn't "Force stop" available for all apps/background processes?

Comment: Moreover, some disabled apps show "XX MB avg memory used in last 3 hours" and others show "No memory used in last 3 hours". All of them were disabled way more than 3 hours ago (~ 20 hours ago).